# Can you use the _ViewStart.cshtml file with MVC inside of WebForms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webforms

I recently discovered that you can use MVC side-by-side with a legacy WebForms application and I'm currently experimenting.  I have created the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file inside of my Views directory, but it's not being called at all.  If I manually specify my layout file in each view page it gets picked up, so this isn't a huge deal but I'd like to avoid having to specify the Layout on every page.

Any idea why the _ViewStart isn't being called?  Is there something manual I have to do since I'm not using an MVC project but a Web Site project?

I don't get any errors, it's just ignored completely.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why the _ViewStart isn't being called?

Because that's Razor. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET WebForms. You must use the Razor view engine for this file to be picked up. Also you must have a web.config file inside the Views folder.

Comment: I do have Razor referenced and the web.config inside the Views folder.  I can use Razor in all other regards it seems _except_ for the _ViewStart file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519541/pagestart-cshtml-vs-viewstart-cshtml-in-asp-net/). Apparently _ViewStart is MVC-only. You can use _PageStart in either framework.