# _PageStart.cshtml vs _ViewStart.cshtml in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I found there's _PageStart.cshtml in http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior and _ViewStart.cshtml in http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts. So what is the difference between _PageStart.cshtml and _ViewStart.cshtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both perform the same function but _ViewStart is MVC-only. You can use _PageStart in either framework.